# Disable map scrolling open street maps

Tags: javascript, html, css, maps

How do I disable mouse interactions or scrolling in an open maps `iframe`? 
I have the following and I put the attribute `scrollwheel="false"` Is there a way via css that can disable scrolling or interactions via css?

```
<iframe id= "mapsource" scrollwheel="false" src="http://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html?bbox=-123.21233510971068%2C49.260691198361066%2C-123.18484783172607%2C49.27329289319553&amp;layer=mapquest&amp;marker=49.26699244809891%2C-123.19858074188232"></iframe>
```

I am open to other options such as using javascript instead to disable scrolling?

Comment: The HTML attribute seems to have been working for you. You were just looking for a method using JavaScript? I am looking for a simple method for disabling scrolling and adding a HTML attribute would be the most trivial. The code copied from OSM includes a `scrolling="no"` attribute but neither `no` nor `yes` have any effect. Same with the `scrollwheel` attribute from your question. Where did you get that from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the controls (zoom in button, zoom out button etc) are important for you,you could use something like below.

```
# The magic - set the pointer-events to none to simply disable the
# scrolling on the map BUT NOT the functionality of the buttons!
# This happens only using leaflet api!
<style>
    #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
</style>

# The map element
<div id="map"></div>

# The css link from leaflet
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA==" crossorigin=""/>
# The js link from leaflet
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-QVftwZFqvtRNi0ZyCtsznlKSWOStnDORoefr1enyq5mVL4tmKB3S/EnC3rRJcxCPavG10IcrVGSmPh6Qw5lwrg==" crossorigin=""></script>

# Custom source code to initialize the map
<script>
    var mymap = L.map("map").setView([37.980114, 23.729924], 17);
    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 19,
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(mymap);
    L.marker([37.980114, 23.729924]).addTo(mymap);

</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try `pointer-events: none;`

```css
#mapsource {
  pointer-events: none;
  }
```

```html
<iframe id= "mapsource" scrollwheel="false" src="http://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html?bbox=-123.21233510971068%2C49.260691198361066%2C-123.18484783172607%2C49.27329289319553&amp;layer=mapquest&amp;marker=49.26699244809891%2C-123.19858074188232"></iframe>
```

Comment: Unfortunately `pointer-events: none` disables all kind of mouse events alltogether. So that map behaves like a static image and there is no visual feedback. I am looking for the behavior like Google Maps: don’t zoom on scroll-wheel but show a hint to use the [+] [-] controls.

Comment: @DanielBöhmer If you add `pointer-events: auto` on control buttons([+][-]) then it should work fine in your case.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to do the same. Disable mouse scroll but keep everything else functional. Options here either completely disabled map, or they didn't work at all.

I ended up having to use Leaflet, which is a library that integrates with Open Street Maps. It's light, quick and easy. Follow their [Quick Start guide](https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/) to set up your map.

To disable scroll, you must pass the Option argument `{scrollWheelZoom:false}` when you initialize the map, like so:

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid', {scrollWheelZoom:false}).setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a method - https://venues.here.com/documentation/sdk/v1/example/disable-zoom-wheel-scroll

```
map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();
```

This implementation also works fine but with the first example you can use it conditionally

```
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        scrollWheelZoom: false,   
        maxZoom: 19,
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(mymap);
```

Comment: This is the documentation for Here Maps, not for OpenStreetMap

Comment: I agree, but this is the method. After this I saw it also in the OSM documentation. No need to use css pointer-event: none or whatever :)

Comment: @MetaTron there seems to be no method scrollWheelZoom