# disable scroll zooming in gonoware/laravel-maps package

Tags: laravel, leaflet, maps

I have used gonoware/laravel-maps packages for displaying pointers in map.Does anyone can help to disable the scrolling zoom ???

```html
 @map([
        'lat' => 22.4487358,
        'lng' => 114.0018454,
        'zoom' => 15,
        'markers' => $markers
      ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add parameter   **gestureHandling: 'none',**

[here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/interaction) is official documentation

Comment: its for google right?
but i am using OpenStreetMaps

Comment: Yes it's for Google maps, Sorry I assumed without asking.

Comment: Check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39736169/disable-map-scrolling-open-street-maps